# turtlebot gmapping with electric

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I upgraded to electric and the gmapping is not workind. I think that the problem is that the base_footprint is not conected to the odometry. I can see it in the RVIZ if I cheeck the TF, in Frames, /base_footprint doesn't have a parent.
Where can I find the code for this TF and change it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12001/turtlebot-gmapping-with-electric./) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osuairt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1049/osuairt/) on 2011-12-06**:
I've had the same issue. However, I compiled the Electric source. As I was doing the teleop around the room, I was getting error messages that kept saying that base_footprint wasn't getting mapped to the odom.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-11-27**:
I haven't changed anything but the position of the kinect on the turtlebot and now it works.... I really don't understand!

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-11-26**:
can you please provide more information what version of the turtlebot software are you running? and can you run rosrun tf view_frames . this will create a pdf of your tf tree, can you please attach the pdf to this page so I can look at it.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-11-21**:
Well, it's juts that the transform from the robot to the odometry is not there, and I want to add this part, but I don't know where the transform code is.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-21**:
Can you describe the phenomenon more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run robot_pose_ekf to get the /odom frame in your tf tree. From what I can tell, in diamondback it was run whenever the robot was "brought up" ... but in electric, this seems to have been changed.

Example launch file:

```
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
  <remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-12-24**:
In more recent releases, the ekf filter is launched with the robot minimal.launch so that odometry is always available.

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-12-23**:
oops, forgot   enclosing tags